# Angular RxJS 5.6 Pipeable bundle optimization

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle, rxjs5

I want to optimize our **Angular 5.2** (with **RxJS 5.6** and **Angular CLI 1.7.1**) application.

Watching [this](https://youtu.be/75ObMlqrhFY?t=16m6s) talk by Igor Minar, I wanted to imitate what he is doing. But he is dealing with `vanilla JS` application + `webpack` and `babel-loader` loader. We have `ejected Angular CLI` application, and there is `@ngtools/webpack` loader. He is talking about the problems with `CommonJS` Modules and that you should use `ES` Modules.

**1st sub question: How do I know if we are using CommonJS modules or ES modules?** Igor himself is saying that it's hard. So... what do I do?

If I understand it correctly, he achieves this by adding this piece of configuration into his webpack loader (provided video is set to this moment in talk):

```
"options": {
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

I added it also, but I have no idea what does it do.

**2nd sub question: how can I find what options can I use and what do they do?** I was trying to find out by reading webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-options-rule-query) but there isn't anything. Is it a `loader` thing and not a `webpack` thing? How can I found out please?

After adding mentioned options and `ModuleConcatenationPlugin()` (also mentioned in the talk, which really helped with the bundle size) I've arrived to this state (webpack bundle analyzer):

[image]

The text *Rx.js 368 modules* is achieved thanks to `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` if I'm not mistaken.

The bundle still seems huge, or am I just crazy? If it is huge, **what am I doing wrong please?**
I checked the whole application and it looks like we are using the imports the correct way:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observale';
somefunction(): Observable<any> {
  ...
  something.map...
}
```

**So what am I missing? What am I doing wrong? What should I focus on? Please.**

Answer (score 0):

One option for you to reduce the amount of modules and avoid importing the whole of `rxjs` operators is if you import them specifically

In your case you would have

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators/scan';
```

If you check the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) you’ll see right at the bottom they are saying it’s a good and efficient solution for when you don’t have control over webpack configuration or you don’t want to be bothered with doing it

I would say that although you might have a tiny more work doing the deep imports one by one it will save you huge headaches with webpack configurations

Comment: I was checking that documentation, and we have control over our webpack configuration. The problem is, we have hundreds of pages and 13 developers. They are bitching about everything, I can't imagine how would I persuade them to do more work :)

Comment: Yes but my suggestion was if you use the deep imports you can achieve the same level of optimisation with less amount of configuration. At the same time you can have a look at the documentation and check what you might be missing on yours

Comment: Did you write that before I edited it? I send it by mistake without the most important part. Do you still think it's the better solution when we have hundreds of pages?

Comment: Well in that case you have two scenarios. Are all the pages importing for the ‘rxjs/operators’ already? If they are then I would say cracking on with the configuration would be better. If you are still writing them I would say it’s a valid option :). But for a hundred of pages application 368 modules seems rather optimised.

Comment: We are still writing them. But if I can't persuade them to follow linter rules, I doubt I'll be able to persuade them to do more import work :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Fair point and I totally understand your pain :). But again for an app that big, 368 modules is not a big deal. It’s usually thousands  before tree shaking and optimisation

Comment: Well we have a lot of third party stuff. And a lot of components that we use through out. Webpack bundle analyzer shows 14.7MB package. And a lot of our users have very old, very bad computers. I want to cut everything I can :)